# nav arrows AROUND the blog view?

Tags: views

## nav arrows AROUND the blog view?

[image: pager]
I've finally gotten pretty close to what I was aiming for on the recent blog entries ***view.***.
I've posted my version above and what I'm aiming for next..
I still need to change the page numbers below for nav arrows on the sides. Is there still something in the views settings I need to be looking for. I saw a place for arrows, but they are always above or below. Is it CSS to push them to either side and let the blogs settle between them?
[image: pagerarrrows]

#### css

```
 #views_slideshow_controls_text_previous_slide_show_of_members-block_1_1 {
    background: url(../sites/all/themes/twodrop/images/comment-arrow.gif);
    /* shows image */

    /* Hide the text. */
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 #block-views-the-blog-block h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[I did find this thread under similar questions, but it seems a bit excessive.. surely a better answer has bubbled up in 4 years?](https://www.drupal.org/node/318565)

.. additional question, so it may warant a seperate thread, but I'm also trying to aling each section. Should I look at moving the title into the header and the date into the footer? Or is this better handled in CSS?
[image: pageralignment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the effect you're after with some clever CSS applied to the default Views pager but it doesn't seem you're very proficient at CSS, and there is a way that may help you get further without coding.

### Carousel Views Format through an additional module

There are some modules that you can use to change your Views `Format` to output views results in a way that resembles what you want, basically a carousel navigation for your views results:

- [jCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel)
- [Slick Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick), [Slick Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_views)
- [Flex Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider)

### Better Pager through an additional module

If you don't think that the carousel solution is good for your case you can change the Pager directly with an additional module.

[Pagerer](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer) is probably your best choice, but there are others if you want to search on your own and compare. Here is a tutorial about how to use it: [How to Create Fancy Pagers in your Drupal Views with Pagerer](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/pagerer/).

### Additional CSS

It's not clear which header and footer you're talking about - the HTML elements? This is CSS related and best solved by using Flexbox or Grid to get the layout with equal column heights but without limiting the column height so you're covered for all content "sizes".